# debugging undefined jest snapshot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have some react code that I am trying to test that looks like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = mount(
    <Provider store={store} >
      <MyPage params={params} location={location} />
    </Provider>
  );
});

test('renders My Page', () => {
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

I am trying to pass location down from react-router, such that I can access the query params in my page and it's components. I have a snapshot in place that works (e.g. shows DOM, etc), but as soon as I add in this new property `wrapper` returns undefined.

I've debugged this and it does not seem to be rendering `<MyPage ...>` at all anymore. I've tried moving the `<MyPage ...>` call into it's own variable, but that did not work either. Finally, I've also tried changing it from mount to shallow (not sure what that does). I've looked at the docs and I can't seem to find anything specifying how I can tell why it would not render\mount.

Are there any tools, techniques or means of detecting why a mounted page\component does not render\mount?

**EDIT 1**

With the help of a colleague, I've figured out my issue - the problem was I was using `PropTypes.shape` instead of `PropTypes.shape()`. I can reproduce this locally, but none of the online sandbox tools seem to make this simple. Further, as it was (with the invalid PropType) it did in fact silently fail in jest. So, is there a way I could have detected this using standard tools and techniques?

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(wrapper.html())` and `console.log(wrapper.debug())`? How do you export `<MyPage />` component? Why do you need `<Provider ...>` in your test? Are you testing `connected` component? Why don't you use `enzyme-to-json` to save your snapshots or maybe you are using it because you configured `snapshotSerializers` in jest? Finally could you clarify what has been working before for you and what doesn't work now.

Comment: I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined` when I add the html or debug function calls. I am not exporting `<MyPage />` as it's a page, not a component. I am exporting a child component, which I'm trying to pass properties to, like so `export const MyAppComponent = connectToModel(MyAppComponentUI, stateToPropsConfig);` I am using provider to pass in mock data to my component.

Comment: Can you post an example in any REPL / javascript-sandbox (  https://repl.it/languages/jest for example ) so anyone can test and understand your problem, please ?

Comment: @DHlavaty I've updated the question, with an edit.

Comment: What is your node version? As for invalid PropTypes, React itself throws console errors so reading `console.error` should answer your question. Here are a few ideas how to achieve this: 1. Put `console.error` inside the test. 2. Run `jest -i`. 3. Add this: `afterAll(done => { setTimeout(() => done(), 3000); });`. 4. Downgrade to Node 6.

Comment: @medik I think you helped me figure it out; the issue was I was running the test in intellij and for some reason it was suppressing the warning about the invalid prop type. When I ran it from the command line (and this is the important part) the warning showed up.

Comment: @medik if you convert to an answer and not a comment, I will accept provided you include my last comment in some form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paraphrasing my comment, React itself throws invalid PropType errors so reading its console log should solve your problem. As you noted: The log might get suppressed if you're using any wrapper for the tests, so running them from bare cli helped.